# Multiple NSObject Initialization Causes code to stop executing

Tags: ios, objective-c

So I have a custom TVShow object that has some base fields like id, showName, airDate etc. which are all either NSStrings or NSIntegers and I am attempting to create a bunch of these objects via some data I have gotten from an API online.

So I loop through my NSArray of JSON data and create a TVShow object for each response:

```
TVShow *show = [[TVShow alloc] initWithData:[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error]];
[self.showArray addObject:show];
```

However, only 7 of these ever get created and then any code below this just ceases to run. I have a NSLog(@"Added"); printing after I create the show and it only gets called 6 times. If I add breakpoints after any of this code, they never get called. I'm not sure what's going on but it must be something to do with how I have set up my TVShow object?

It currently looks like:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface TVShow : NSObject

@property NSInteger showID;
@property NSString *showName;
@property NSString *airDate;
@property double rating;
@property NSString *imageUrl;
@property NSString *showSummary;
@property NSString *episodeSummary;
@property NSInteger season;
@property NSInteger episode;

- (id)initWithData:(NSDictionary *)data;

@end
```

and the .m file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "TVShow.h"

@implementation TVShow

- (id)initWithData:(NSDictionary*)data {
    self = [super init];
    if(self) {

        [self buildObjectFromData:data];
    }
    return self;
}
-(void)buildObjectFromData:(NSDictionary*)data {
    NSDictionary *dict = [data objectForKey:@"_embedded"];
    NSDictionary *dict2 = [dict objectForKey:@"nextepisode"];
    NSDictionary *dict3 = [data objectForKey:@"image"];

    NSString *airDate = [dict2 valueForKey:@"airstamp"];
    NSInteger season = [[dict2 valueForKey:@"season"] integerValue];
    NSInteger episode = [[dict2 valueForKey:@"episode"] integerValue];
    NSString *episodeSummary = [dict2 valueForKey:@"summary"];
    NSString *showName = [data valueForKey:@"name"];
    NSString *showSummary = [data valueForKey:@"summary"];
    NSString *imageUrl = [dict3 valueForKey:@"medium"];
    NSInteger showID = [[data valueForKey:@"id"] integerValue];

    self.airDate = airDate;
    self.showName = showName;
    self.season = season;
    self.episode = episode;
    self.showSummary = [self stringByStrippingHTML:showSummary];
    self.episodeSummary = [self stringByStrippingHTML:episodeSummary];
    self.imageUrl = imageUrl;
    self.showID = showID;
}

-(NSString *) stringByStrippingHTML:(NSString*)string {
    NSRange r;
    NSString *s = string;
    while ((r = [s rangeOfString:@"<[^>]+>" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch]).location != NSNotFound)
        s = [s stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:r withString:@""];
    return s;
}

@end
```

If I create the object as just: [[TVShow alloc] init]; everything works fine, so it must be something wrong with this model is what I'm thinking. I'm unsure of what to try next, but any help would be greatly appreciated here.

Comment: When you say "ceases to run", are you talking about a crash? Please post the error message.

Comment: Your call to `initWithData:` contains a nested method call to `JSONObjectWithData` so your assumption that the problem is within your init is incorrect. Start by breaking out the nested call and checking its error return.

Comment: No there is no crash. But any code placed after my TVShow initialization call just ceases to run after the seventh one is created (ie I place a breakpoint beneath it which never gets hit after the 7th is created).

Comment: I also investigated the nested call and it seems to be working properly. No errors ever occur in it from what I found.

Comment: Use the debugger; hit pause and look at the stack frames to see where your code is executing or use the time profiler instrument. It may not be in the code you have shown but if it is, my guess is it is stuck in the while loop in `stringByStrippingHTML`

Comment: oh wtf that is what it was. I found that snippet online, should have looked more closely.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there were cases that casued:

```
-(NSString *) stringByStrippingHTML:(NSString*)string {
    NSRange r;
    NSString *s = string;
    while ((r = [s rangeOfString:@"<[^>]+>" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch]).location != NSNotFound)
        s = [s stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:r withString:@""];
    return s;
}
```

to go into infinite loops. Removing this snippet fixed the freeze.